# My code is creating multiple Tkinter windows erroneously

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The following code should generate 1 main window with a number of other nested windows. It should then display the updating of a text window as the code writes text to it. However the code generates multiple windows, that contain nothing, along with the main one which has all the correctly formatted windows.

```
class AdventuresofTOT(Tk.Tk):

def setup(self,Tk):
    global main 
    main = Tk.PanedWindow(root)
    main.config(orient=Tk.VERTICAL)

    global textwindow
    textwindow = Tk.Text(main)
    textwindow.config(relief=Tk.SUNKEN, font=("Consolas",10), height=57, width=65)
    main.add(textwindow)
    textwindow.pack()

    bottom = Tk.PanedWindow(main)
    bottom.config(orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL)
    main.add(bottom)
    bottom.pack(fill=Tk.X,side=Tk.BOTTOM)

    IWlabel = Tk.Label(bottom)
    IWlabel.config(text = "User Input")
    bottom.add(IWlabel)
    IWlabel.pack(fill=Tk.X, expand=1, side=Tk.LEFT)

    global inputwindow 
    inputwindow = Tk.Entry(bottom)
    bottom.add(inputwindow)
    inputwindow.pack(fill=Tk.X, expand=1, side=Tk.RIGHT)

    main.pack()

def writer(self, Tk, textobject, n):
    for line in textobject:
            textwindow.insert(Tk.INSERT, "\n" + line)
            AdventuresofTOT().sleeper(n)

def sleeper(self,n):
    textwindow.update()
    time.sleep(n)

def deleter(self):
    textwindow.delete(1.0, Tk.END)

def init(self, Tk):
    AdventuresofTOT().setup(Tk)
    #PhaseOne
    f = open('PhaseOne.txt', 'r')
    self.writer(Tk, f, 0.1)
    f.close()
    AdventuresofTOT().sleeper(3)
    self.deleter()
    #PhaseTwo


root = AdventuresofTOT()
root.init(Tk)
root.mainloop()
```

Additionally, there are single line spaces between my text when writing to the text window, how do i remove them? It's important as the displayed text is text art.

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of the code in your question.

Comment: You are creating brand new `AdventuresofTOT` objects all over the place, each of which creates its own window and set of widgets.  Only the instance assigned to `root` should exist, all of those other places should use `self` instead to refer to the existing instance.

Comment: Will fix that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jasonharper 's comment was correct and solved the problem,
I referenced the `AdventuresofTOT`object incorrectly and should have rather used `self` instead.

All credits to @jasonharper